# Supervisord-like tool for Windows

Tags: windows

I'm used to using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) in my Unix machines and now I must do the same thing for Windows. Sadly, supervisord does not run under Windows machines.

Does anyone know any alternatives?

Comment: A quick look at supervisord.org suggests that this functionality is already built into Windows.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Where did you see it? Perhaps the docs are outdated...
From the docs: "Supervisor works on just about everything except for Windows." http://supervisord.org/introduction.html

Comment: I mean that the tools built into Windows already do the jobs that Supervisord appears to be for, or perhaps it would be more accurate to say that the jobs Supervisord appears to do aren't applicable in Windows.  Anyway, can you describe what you actually want to use it for?

Comment: Yes, I have a nginx webserver that load balance its requests to some tornardo webservers. In this case, I'm must be sure that the tornados are up and running every time. I've done the same thing before using Ubuntu server and Supervisord and it worked well.

Comment: So you want to be notified if the web servers haven't started up successfully?

Comment: No, I want a monitoring system that starts/restarts them in case of failure, just like supervisord does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows can do this for you.

Open the Services control panel.  Select your service.  Go to the Recovery tab.  You can select options for the first, second and subsequent service failures.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Cygwin to run `supervisord` under Windows, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629813/is-there-windows-analog-to-supervisord

Quoted instructions:

> 1. If you have not done it yet, install Cygwin. During the installation process, select Python.
> 2. From the Cygwin terminal, install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) as usual.
> 3. Create a virtualenv for supervisord, and then install as usual:
>
>    ```
>     pip install supervisor
>    ```
> 4. Configure supervisord in the usual way. Keep in mind that supervisord will be running with Cygwin, so you better use paths the Cygwin way (C:\myservers\project1 translates to /cygdrive/c/myservers/project1 in Cygwin).
> 5. Now you probably want to install supervisord as a service. Here's how I do it:
>
>    ```
>     cygrunsrv --install supervisord --path /home/Administrator/supervisor/venv/bin/python --args "/home/Administrator/supervisor/venv/bin/supervisord -n -c /home/Administrator/supervisor/supervisord.conf"
>    ```
> 6. Go to the Windows service manager and start the service supervisord that you just installed.

---

The above solution helped me control a Tomcat instance running in a regular user session (instead of running as a service):

```
[program:tomcat]
command=/cygdrive/c/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
numprocs=1
directory=/cygdrive/c/tomcat
autostart=false
```

You can set `supervisord` to run at logon and then you can use its web interface to start/stop tomcat